# Bash completion in function?

Tags: bash, function, bash-completion, pathname

I currently have the following Bash function:

```sh
function xcd {
        if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
                echo "Usage: xcd [<path>]" >&2
                return 1
        fi

        cd "/some/commonly/used/path/${1}"
}
```

I'd like for this to support Bash completion - when I type `xcd foo`, I'd like it to complete as though I'd typed `cd /some/commonly/used/path/foo`. Is there any way to get Bash to be smart about this - presumably by observing how `${1}` is used - without just writing a Bash completion by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your function in your `~/.bashrc` with this:

```
CDPATH="/some/commonly/used/path"
```

I assume that CDPATH is not used so far. Source your `~/.bashrc` and then you can use `cd foo` with bash's
completion.